# How to pass className to `h${headingLevel}` custom tag

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I'm creating a custom component with a dynamic-level heading:

```js
const HeadingTag = `h${headingLevel}`;
...
<HeadingTag className='heading'>
  {headingText}
</HeadingTag>
```

However, I get the following error:

```
error TS2322: Type '{ children: string; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
```

How can I pass default HTML attributes to custom tags that resolve to default HTML tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic tag names, but the type of the tag name will have to be a string literal type or a union of string literal types corresponding to tag names.

Unfortunately typescript can't understand that `h${headingLevel}` will evaluate to one of the `h` tags (event if `headingLevel` were an apropriate numeric or string literal type union, typescript just does not have the machinery for this).

The simplest solution in this case since we have more information than the compiler does is to use a type assertion to let typescript know `HeadingTag` will be `'h1' | 'h2' | 'h3' | 'h4' | 'h5'| 'h6'`:

```
const HeadingTag = `h${headingLevel}` as 'h1' | 'h2' | 'h3' | 'h4' | 'h5'| 'h6';
<HeadingTag className='heading'>
    {headingText}
</HeadingTag>
```